# Short web-original story about eldritch horrors repelling an alien first-contact

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, horror

I've been trying to find a web-original short story I read a couple years back.

I found it on Imgur, text on an image, fairly long, it may have been a 4chan greenpost.

The essential premise was a reminiscence from the point of view of aliens encountering humanity. Everything goes really well but something is subtly wrong.
Then the protagonist alien encounters a human child, and perceives something monstrous and shadowy "behind" them. 
It turns out that humanity has eldritch horrors looking out for them and they don't tolerate the aliens' interference.
Humanity has no idea why the aliens packed up and ran away overnight.

I thought I read it in a compilation of "Humanity F*ck Yeah" stories, but haven't been able to find it again.

Comment: That's not going to be a narrow search. Back in the 1990s there were fanfic stories with the premise "All the monsters and mutants on the X-Files fight the alien invasion plan".

Comment: I don't remember a human *child* being involved, but this sounds kinda like David Weber's *Out of the Dark*, based off a short story in an anthology called *Warriors*.